# Multiply hh:mm with number in excel

Tags: excel

I have a total of hours in hh:mm format and I need to multiply it with hourly rate for example 22$ per hours. How can I achieve this in excel?

[image]

Expectation is since its 49:30 hours, it should perform below formula `49:50 & 22 = 1089`

Comment: Multiply it by 22 * 24.

Comment: I did not get you what is 24 here ? how it will work @BigBen

Comment: In Excel, one day = 1, so you need to multiply by 24 hours to get the equivalent in hours.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the hh:mm format to timevalue and multiply by 24 (because 1 = 1 day), and then multiply by hourly rate: (Assume hour data in A1)

`=(TIMEVALUE("00:00:00")+A1)*24*22`